# Unusable using conditionals

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I have a var that is only defined when running vagrant:

```
is_vagrant: yes
```

When I run other playbook it's not defined as the var is not included.

When I do in ansible:

```
when: is_vagrant is defined
```

It works like a charm when it's defined or not defined.

But when I use something like this:

```
when: gitclone.changed or is_vagrant is defined
```

it just skips the task even when is_vagrant var is included. I'm not sure why?

Answer (score 1):

I've given up trusting ansible to do the right thing when it comes to variable expansions. So even when ansible tries to misguide me with messages like "*you don't need to use `{{}}` or `""`*", I still do.

Did you try:

```
when: "{{ gitclone.changed or is_vagrant is defined }}"
```

-- edit --

```
when: "{{ is_vagrant is defined or ( gitclone is defined and gitclone.changed ) }}"
```

> Why do I have to check the defined. .changed is true or false I assume?

If you want the task to 'fail' when the variable is not defined, then you don't have to check if it's defined. But if you don't want the `UndefinedError: 'git_output'` error then you have check.

`changed` is inside `git_output` so if `git_output` isn't defined `git_output.changed` isn't defined by extension.

Comment: UndefinedError: 'git_output' is undefined actually not sure what am I comparing.

Comment: @gtheys I suppose you mean `gitclone` is undefined? If yes, there is your problem.

Comment: yes indeed I copied from my script and named it different :)

Comment: It's off course not defined. Why do I have to check the defined. .changed is true or false I assume?

Comment: So both don't return true/false? What do they return can't find it in unusable docs even in jinja2 it's not clear. (at least for me)

Comment: @gtheys, yeah documentation of jinja and more so ansible isn't the best. I updated the answer.

Comment: I solved the is_vagrant part by variable precedence. So this var is always defined. before the gitclone.changed didn't give a undefined error ;)